# Return values from list that are not present in another list using LinQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Hey i have list of integers which are id's.
I want to create async method that returns list of id's that are not present in dbContext table. I have something like this.

```
public async Task<List<int>> NotExisting(List<int> inputIds, CancellationToken cancellationtoken)
{
var notExisting = await _dbContext.Table
    .Where(x => !inputIds.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x => x.Id).ToListAsync();

return notExisting;
}
```

Now its just taking all of the elements in table that doesnt match the input id. I want to only get the elements from `inputIds` that are not present in `_dbContext.Table`. I know i am taking wrong thing in `Select` but i dont know how to access the current id in `inputIds`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to switch the `SELECT` source, since the IDs you want to have are ultimately NOT coming from the database:

```
var allIDsInDb = (await _dbContext.Table.Select(x => x.Id).ToListAsync()).ToHashSet();
// ToHashSet() was for faster lookups in the next line
var notExisting = inputIds.Except(allIDsInDb).ToList();
```

**UPD**: If you don't want to pull all the IDs from the database, you still need to find out which IDs from your list DO exist in the db, so just add a condition:

```
var allIDsInDb = (await _dbContext.Table.Where(x => inputIds.Contains(x.Id)).Select(x => x.Id).ToListAsync()).ToHashSet();
// ToHashSet() was for faster lookups in the next line
var notExisting = inputIds.Except(allIDsInDb).ToList();
```

Comment: So theres no way of doing it without pulling all id's from database?

Comment: There is, but then your code would be a bit wordier. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @konrad8767 updated. After a second thought, it actually became even more compact - I've somehow forgot about `IEnumerable.Except` method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=net-7.0.

Comment: Using hashset = upvote :)